# Android browser : programmatically change focused input value

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm trying to enforce a date format (00/00/0000) on a text input

(the input has a maxlength="10" and validation is handled separately).

Here is the code i use (jQuery) :

```
        $(function() {

            $('input').live('keydown keyup', function(e) {

                var str = $(this).val(), len = str.length;

                if (e.which != 8) { /* Backspace */

                    if (len == 2 || len == 5) {

                        str += '/';

                        $(this).val(str);
                    }   
                }
            });
        });
```

This works fine everywhere i tested except for Android native browser and Dolphin browser on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

The problem is you can't change the input value while it is focused : the slashes appear at the end of the character string once the focus is lost.

This bug is documented : http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39569

A somewhat hacky solution would be losing and regaining focus when the value needs to be updated, but that makes you lose the keyboard every time.

Any suggestions on how i can find a way around this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

and specify:

```
$("input").mask("99/99/9999");
```

I don't have a Samsung tablet myself to test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the reason I need to write the script myself is precisely because the plugins I tested (including the one you mention) are buggy on Android (probably due to the same bug btw).

Comment: Ok. Only other solution that occurs to me is to have 3 input fields - one each for DD, MM, and YYYY and tab automatically from one to the next after you have entered the 2 digits.